# How to share tables between computers with local postgres?

Tags: postgresql-9.2

I work in a small office that has no server capaobilities but we need to share large data tables (~50MM rows) between each other every week.  Currentlt we use a series of Microsoft Access tables passed around on flash drives.

Is there a way for me to put postgres tables onto a flash drive and have another computer be able to open and use them on their postgres program?

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL is a fully fledged RDBMS - install it on a central server (nominate one of your machines if you don't have one) and use it as a database server.

It sounds to me like you're using a Portable Version of PostgreSQL at the moment - so maybe whatever software you are using with it might need to be configured appropriately for this.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.  So if I setup one machine as a server, would others get the tables from the intranet connected to it or some other method?  Or would they link to it and run their queries on the server machine?

Comment: Indeed - but your comments (and no disrespect) suggest to me that you might like to get help from a developer / DBA... You need someone who understands a remote connection to a database. If you are using software on this, ask whoever wrote it how to configure for a central server.